# .NET Regex: Is {0} quantifier works?

Tags: c#, regex

In LINQPad (.NET ) all these expressions returns "True":

```
new Regex(@"\w{0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"(\w){0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"[\w]{0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"([\w]){0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"\w{0,0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"(\w){0,0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"[\w]{0,0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"([\w]){0,0}").IsMatch("aa aa ZZ Z").Dump();
new Regex(@"([a]){0,0}").IsMatch("aaaaZZZ").Dump();
```

Why?

Comment: They return true because they should match, are you looking to use the string terminators `^` and `$`?

Comment: This isn't an answer, just a comment.  It actually looks like you are trying to Check if there are No Word Characters.  Is that right?  Just make a regex to look for `\w`, if it returns a length, there are word characters.  If not, there are no word characters.  I'd also suggest checking out the answer from "recursive".  He actually answers your question.

Comment: @Suamere, not exactly. Real issue was partially pointed by both Matthew and recursive but Tim summarize both of them. And because of this, his answer is most complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that your plan is to make sure that a certain character isn't present in the source string by using the `{0}` quantifier on it. That's not going to work like this. The `{0}` quantifier itself is useless here - it means "match the previous token zero times". This is true for all strings, even the empty string. Zero is only useful as a lower bound, for example in `a{0,5}` to match zero to five `a`s.

Regexes are designed to *match* text, so you need to go through some contortions to make them *not match* text. For example:

```
Regex(@"^\W*$")  // syntactic sugar for Regex(@"^[^\w]*$")
```

matches only if the entire string consists of non-alphanumeric characters.

```
Regex(@"^[^a]*$")
```

matches only if the entire string consists of characters other than `a`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he didn't ask a closed-ended question.  Threw me off that you started your answer with "No."  And it's false to say "`{0}` can't be enforced like this".  Obviously it can, and as you know, always returns true.  You did state that {0} will always return true, but he already knows that, and he wants to know why.  You also continued on to explain a bit about how Regex works, but still, sadly, never answered the question.  So I'm curious why you were marked as the answer.  My goal here is just hopefully to bring your attention more toward what a user's question exactly is.

Comment: @Suamere, Actually I was trying to understand, why there a big different (as I thought) in logic between {0,0} and, example, {2,2}. And Tim give me a good explanation of this - "... it means 'match the previous token zero times'. This is true for all strings, even the empty string.". Also, he pointed me what I forgot about string terminators - this was the reason why I had wrong understanding about meaning of {0}.

Comment: Yup, definitely.  Looks like Tim edited his answer and it is actually very clear now.  +1

Answer (score 4):

Regex is better at positive assertions than negative.  `new Regex(@"\w{0}")` is the same as `new Regex(@"")`.  `{0}` means to match zero instances of `\w`.  Since there is nothing else in the regex, it will match all input strings.

Comment: Correct.  'New Regex(@"")' is searching for nothing. Another way of saying it is: 'New Regex(@"")' is not searching for any width assertions.  For example "a" is one width.  "" is zero-width.  In most of the user's examples, there are 11 (or more) matches.  The Zero-Width position between each character.  So it actually does find matches, thusly it returns true.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying on each expressions to match a zero-width string that is present in all strings of the world. Thus it returns true.